# Choosing your own initialisation points for kmeans

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

Kmeans clustering will randomly select the initialisation points and then run the algorithm until convergence is reached. Is there a way I can choose my own initialisation points and pass them into the kmeans library in scikit-learn. I could not find any way to do that in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`, you are able to pass in the initialization points using the `init` argument:

> init : {‘k-means++’, ‘random’}, callable or array-like of shape
> (n_clusters, n_features), default=’k-means++’ Method for
> initialization:
>
> ‘k-means++’ : selects initial cluster centers for k-mean clustering in
> a smart way to speed up convergence. See section Notes in k_init for
> more details.
>
> ‘random’: choose n_clusters observations (rows) at random from data
> for the initial centroids.
>
> If an array is passed, it should be of shape (n_clusters, n_features)
> and gives the initial centers.
>
> If a callable is passed, it should take arguments X, n_clusters and a
> random state and return an initialization.